# FAILED: ParseException line 4:0 cannot recognize input near ')' 'COMMENT' ''V1.0'' in column specification

Tags: hive

I have seen many questions that have this kind of error on SO, and I have tried their proposed solutions, but none of them worked.

Here is my script:

```
CREATE TABLE default.my_table(

)COMMENT 'V1.0' 
row format delimited fields terminated BY '\t' lines terminated BY '\n';
```

I have other scripts that have no columns, but are getting executed fine, but somehow this script is causing an error when executing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A Hive table should have at least one column. The column list can be specified explicitly or provided via an external schema.

For tables that have lot of columns, this can be helpful. Manually specifying each column is tedious and error-prone, and having them auto-populated is desirable.

**This approach illustrated with Avro format**

**Sample schema file** (`my_table.avsc`)

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "dummy_record",
  "namespace" : "so",
  "doc" : "Test schema",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "column1",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  },
  {
    "name" : "column2",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }]
}
```

**Upload the schema file to HDFS**

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /avsc-schemas
hadoop fs -put my_table.avsc /avsc-schemas
```

**Create a Hive table (No columns need to be specified in create statement)**

```
CREATE TABLE default.my_table
COMMENT 'V1.0' 
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
  TBLPROPERTIES (
    'avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///avsc-schemas/my_table.avsc');
```

**Check the Hive table. It has two columns, even though none were specified in create statement.**

```
desc default.my_table;
col_name    data_type   comment
column1     string
column2     string
```